# Table-like subplot with labels in X and Y

Tags: matlab, matlab-hg2

I am trying to plot some figures in a table like way.

so e.g. I have 3x4 grid of subplots (each one is a surf) and I want to have labels in the X and Y axis, something like:

```
    thingy1     thingy2     thingy3
a1   sp341       sp342        ...
a2     ...        ...         ...
a3     ...        ...         ...
a4     ...        ...         ...
```

where `sp341` means `subplot(3,4,1)`. To do this, I tried for `thingyN` using `title` and for `aN` using 'ylabel' (I view the surfs from z, so it works). This give me some nice results.

However, I also want `axis off`, so only the surface is seen! (what an annoying guy I am). As you may suspect, this also deletes the ylabels, with the axis.

Any way of workaround-ing this? I just need it for reporting purposes, so it doesnt need to be a general solution, an "ugly" way of solving it may work (as using ylabel is).

Comment: I think you can use `text`, if `axis off`. You are plotting them in at least one loop I suppose so can't you access the labels with your loop variables?

Comment: mmm im not sure if I uderstood your suggestion @Kamtal. I can access the labels indeed, but for `text`, dont I need the location? how would I know the location of the text?

Comment: @Kamtal indeed that may be the answer. How woul I know wich X and Y to use? I could try doing it by hand until it fits, but it hurts me to do it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `axis off` command hides the labels, but does not delete them.
In order for them to appear you should do something like that:

```
h1 = ylabel('a1');
.
.
.
hN = ylabel('aN');
axis off
set(h1,'Visible','on')
.
.
.
set(hN,'Visible','on')
```